# How do I install nitrotasks?

Tags: software-installation, 15.10

I want to install the program from nitrotasks.com. 
But there is no version available for Ubuntu 15.10. So I download it from https://launchpad.net/nitrotasks  and I get two folders with python files, how do I install it?

In one folder there is a `builder.py` do I need to run this?

Answer (score 1):

Donwload and install with the steps below:

```
wget  https://launchpad.net/nitrotasks/trunk/1.5.1/+download/nitrotasks_1.5.1.tar.gz
tar xf nitrotasks_1.5.1.tar.gz
cd quickly_trunk
sudo checkinstall --pkgname nitrotasks python setup.py install
```

And to prevent [your](http://pastebin.com/njK3nHRG) error in xfce, install `gir1.2-unity-5.0`

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-unity-5.0
```

---

Your binary is in

```
/usr/local/bin/nitrotasks
```

a desktop file is also available, run the app via <kbd>Nitro</kbd>

```
/usr/local/share/applications/nitrotasks.desktop
```

Check all other files with

```
dpkg -L nitrotasks
```

Remove it with

```
sudo dpkg -r nitrotasks
```

or with

```
sudo apt-get remove nitrotasks
```

Comment: Now i get another error: http://pastebin.com/RJhFyVte

Comment: That's a runtime error and no installation thing.

Comment: You should ask a new question with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a single nitrotasks_1.5.1.tar.gz file in the Downloads section.

Download it, untar the file and run `python setup.py` inside the folder.

Answer (score 0):

run the following code:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/nitrotasks/trunk/1.5.1/+download/nitrotasks_1.5.1.tar.gz
tar -xvzf nitrotasks_1.5.1.tar.gz
cd quickly_trunk
chmod +x setup.py
sudo apt-get install python-distutils-extra
./setup.py
```

Comment: more specfically you first have to `./setup.py build` then `sudo ./setup.py install`

Comment: I get this error when i launch it   http://pastebin.com/njK3nHRG         i am using xfce